# Opengl ES 1.1/Android -- The texture-mapping-to-a-square debacle of 2011

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, textures

I am trying to map a texture onto a square where the texture stretches to fit the square. Currently the texture maps, but it doesn't map to the correct location and OGL performs some skewing or such that is unbeknownst to me. The image is 64x64 and the squares I've tried are from -2 to 2 (hor and ver) and -1 to 1. Here is the image:

[image]
The texture code is:

```
float texture[] = { 0,0,0,1, 1,0,1,1 };
ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
FloatBuffer textureBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
textureBuffer.put(texture);
textureBuffer.flip();
int[] buffer = new int[1];
gl11.glGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);
textureCoordPointer = buffer[0];
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY, textureCoordPointer);
gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY, textureBuffer.capacity() 
   * 4, textureBuffer, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY, 0);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context
   .getResources(),R.drawable.afd);
int textures[] = new int[1];
gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
texturePointer = textures[0];
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturePointer);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
bitmap.recycle();
```

and the code for the rendering is:

```
gl11.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPointerSquare);
gl11.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);       
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexPointerSquare);
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturePointer);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY, textureCoordPointer);
gl11.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

gl11.glPushMatrix();
gl11.glScalef(.4f,.4f,0);
gl11.glColor4f(1,1,1,1);
gl11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, indicesSquare, 
   GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
gl11.glPopMatrix();
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

And the square:

```
GL11 gl11 = (GL11) gl;
FloatBuffer vertexSquareBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(verticesSquare * 3 * 4)
.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();

ShortBuffer indexSquareBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indicesSquare * 2)
.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();

float vertices[] = { 1f, 1f, 0, 1f, -1f, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, -1f, -1f, 0 };
short indices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
vertexSquareBuffer.put(vertices);
indexSquareBuffer.put(indices);
indexSquareBuffer.flip();
vertexSquareBuffer.flip();
int[] bufferSquare = new int[1];
gl11.glGenBuffers(1, bufferSquare, 0);
vertexPointerSquare = bufferSquare[0];
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPointerSquare);
gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexSquareBuffer.capacity() * 4,
    vertexSquareBuffer, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
gl11.glGenBuffers(1, bufferSquare, 0);
indexPointerSquare = bufferSquare[0];
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexPointerSquare);
gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexSquareBuffer.capacity() * 2,
    indexSquareBuffer, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

I am using an ortho perspective
`gl.glOrthof(-windowRatio, windowRatio, -1,1, -4, 4)`
. I have tried drawArrays(), which makes no difference, and also using many combinations of `glTexParameter`. The problem seems twofold: (1) the image doesn't stretch to fit, and (2) only the left triangle of the square correctly renders the texture.  Something I've noticed is that changing the texture coordinates has no effect on the image. How do I get this to work as intended? Thanks for looking.

Comment: From the images, your square is split into 2 triangles different mappings for the upper right and lower left triangle. Upper right is skewed.

Comment: It probably won't help, but any chance of posting the setup for indexPointerSquare and vertexPointerSquare? As an unrelated style observation: you could dump indexPointerSquare and just use glDrawArrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY` as buffer binding point. That is just wrong. The `glTexCoordPointer` sources its data from the current `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, like the `glVertexPointer`. So in your first part substitute

```
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY, textureCoordPointer);
gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY, textureBuffer.capacity() 
   * 4, textureBuffer, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY, 0);
```

by

```
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordPointer);
gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer.capacity() 
   * 4, textureBuffer, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

and in the rendering code substitute

```
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY, textureCoordPointer);
```

by

```
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordPointer);
```

This works because the `gl...Pointer` commands take their data from the buffer that is bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` at the moment they are called. So just select the appropriate buffer, then call `gl...Pointer` and then you can bind another buffer to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` (but the index buffer needs to be bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` when calling `glDrawElements`, of course. But as Tommy already mentioned in a comment, you could also just go without the trivial index buffer and with `glDrawArrays`).

So, as the call to `glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY, ...)` fails (as `GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY` is no valid binding point), you have the vertex buffer still bound when setting the texcoord pointer. But since you specify your vertices to have 3 components and your texcoords 2, you actually get `{ 1f, 1f, 0f, 1f, -1f, 0f, -1f, 1f }` as texture coordinates (the first eight values of your vertex array). So as you render your array as

```
2   0

3   1
```

you get as texture coords:

```
-1,0   1,1

-1,1   0,1
```

After making the proposed changes you will get

```
1,0   0,0

1,1   0,1
```

So your texture is still flipped horizontally and vertically (I don't know if that's intended). You have to make sure that your textrue coordinates match your vertices. But after changing your above mentioned buffer error, it should at least look a bit nicer.

Comment: Well deserved +50. That fixed the problem and I appreciate the thorough explanation.